# Binary tree Basics in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a binary tree data structure of:

```
//Declare Data Structure
struct CP {
    int id;         //ID of the Node
    int data;       //Data of the Node
    CP * left;      //Pointer to the Left Subtree 
    CP * right;     //Pointer to the Right Subtree
};

typedef CP * CPPtr;
```

Without changing the tree structure, how do I actually calculate the depth if given a node id. (id is a unique indicator to each tree node)

Comment: Define "fails drastically".  And what's the point of the `nodeID(tree)!=id` condition?

Comment: define "the depth of a given node id"

Answer (score 1):

your code is lack of some base steps or necessary initializations.

```
 BTree_Helper(BTree *Tree){// this is roughly written like pseudo code
    if(TLeft == NULL && TRight == NULL){
      depth of tree = 0 ;       
    }
    else if (TLeft == NULL){
      depth of tree = depth of right tree ;       
    }
    else if(TRight==NULL){
      depth of tree = depth of left tree;        
    }
    else{
      depth of tree = the maximum between depth of left and depth of right;
    }
 }
```

I just gave some hints for your convinence.
Think carefully and try as many test suites as possible.

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate more on it? I didn't really understand how to do it sorry. THank you

Comment: @PeiChin dude,im at office now..but the idea is,you count the depth recursively.imagine there is a binary tree with dep_x on left and dep_y on right,the depth of this binary tree would be the maximum between two branches.and dont forget to consider when this is an empty tree or this is technically a tree with one of both branches null,or what u call,a list or sth.

Answer (score 0):

Read about basic tree/graph search algorithms: [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS) and [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (DFS). Try implementing DFS both recursively and with an explicit `stack<T>`. Implement BFS using a `queue<T>`.

Pay attention to the efficiency of your approach. If you want to look-up the depth of nodes repeatedly it will probably be much faster to store the depth of every node in the tree in some sort of look-up table. Ideally a hash table but a `map<T1, T2>` will do in most cases.

You'll learn a lot from the above exercises. Good luck!

Comment: Is there any other place to look up on things that you have mentioned other than wikipedia. I tried to study it before I started but its so hard to understand. Thanks

Comment: specifically: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=graphsDataStrucs2

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what y26jin suggested, maybe something like this?

```
BTree_Helper(CP *TreeNode) {
    CP *TLeft = TreeNode->left;
    CP *TRight = TreeNode->right;
    if(TLeft == NULL && TRight == NULL){
      return 0;       
    }
    else if (TLeft == NULL){
      return 1+(BTree_Helper(TRight));       
    }
    else if(TRight==NULL){
      return 1+(BTree_Helper(TLeft));        
    }
    else{
      return 1+max(BTree_Helper(TLeft),BTree_Helper(TRight));
    }
 }
```

I can't actually test the code right now, sorry if I'm way off here. But I think something along these lines should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `id` is the search key for the tree. In other words, the `id` of any node on the left subtree is less than the `id` of this node, and the `id` of any node on the right subtree is greater than the `id` of this node. Also, `id` is assumed to be unique.

To find a node with a given ID, given a pointer to the root node of the tree, you just do:

```
CP* find(CP* root, int searchID)
{
    // Starting point.
    CP* node = root;
    while(node)
    {
        // Search hit?
        if(node->id == searchID)
            return node;
        // Turn left or right?
        if(node->id < searchID)
            node = node->left;
        else
            node = node->right;
    }
    return 0; // No node with the given ID found.
}
```

Finding depth is a simple modification of this function: instead of returning a node, you keep count of how many levels you descend. A depth of 0 means the root node is what you want; a depth of 1 means either the left or right nodes; a depth of 2 means any of their direct children, etc. So it's really how many times you have to loop:

```
int depth(CP* root, int searchID)
{
    // Starting point.
    CP* node = root;
    int depth = 0;
    while(node)
    {
        // Search hit?
        if(node->id == searchID)
            return depth;
        // Descending a level...
        ++depth;
        // Turn left or right?
        if(node->id < searchID)
            node = node->left;
        else
            node = node->right;
    }
    return -1; // No node with the given ID found.
}
```

Note the special value -1 for "not found".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing the depth of a node's subtree in that node.  Then you can just update the depth of the tree as you add nodes to it.  Whenever you add a node, back out of the tree, updating the depth of each node along the path to the root on the way out.  If at any point, the new depth of a node's modified subtree is not greater than the depth of the node's other subtree, you can short-circuit.

The benefits to this approach are:

1. It's worst-case performance is O(log n) (assuming that the tree is balanced).
2. It is extremely easy to write non-recursively

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the depth from any node using recursion:

```
int countChildren(CPPtr node) {

    if ( node != null )
        return 1 + countChildren(node->left) + countChildren(node->right);

    else 
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: "return 1 + countChildren(node->left) + countChildren(node->right);" should be replaced by "return 1 + max(countChildren(node->left),countChildren(node->right));".

Comment: This is depth calculation, not total node calculation. Please fix your code.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass pointers to lDepth and rDepth, not the values themselves, like so:

`nodeDepth_Helper(tree,id, &lDepth, &rDepth);`

Furthermore, I think the arguments to nodeDepth_helper should be declared as pointers to ints:

`void nodeDepth_Helper(CPPtr tree, int id, int* lDepth,int* rDepth)`

making these changes throughout should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried that but didn't solve my problem instead all the depth read are now 0. Thanks